How to Install plugins and Configure Micro for Consistent Formatting with VSCode?
I want to have autoformatting upon save on my Micro text editor that is compatible with my Visual Studio Code formatting. Here is my settings.json file for my C# .NET and WPF XAML profile:
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DotJoshJohnson.xml"
  }
}

I am on Windows OS and mostly using cmd but I am ok with PowerShell if required. I see that there are some formatting plugins:

fmt-micro
micro-autofmt

I have installed Micro via Chocolatey choco install micro -y.
I want to know how to install any of the plugins and how to configure my Micro so I have compatible formatting between Micro and VSCode.
